# Escape for net.sf.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, json-lib

When I have to give a `JSONObject.fromObject` this popping an exception here 'true' = 'true' pq are the single quote inside another single quote, someone knows some kind of escape character for this API?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{gA:[ {c:{f:'C#',o:'=',v1:' ('true' = 'true' ) ' }}]}";


        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();



        try {

            JsonConfig cfg = new JsonConfig();
            cfg.setRootClass(LinkedHashMap.class);
            cfg.setArrayMode(JsonConfig.MODE_OBJECT_ARRAY);
            cfg.setHandleJettisonSingleElementArray(false);
            JSONObject jsonObjeto = JSONObject.fromObject(json, cfg);
            System.out.println(jsonObjeto.toString());
        } catch (final JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Exception:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character net.sf.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 31 of {gA:[ {c:{f:'C#',o:'=',v1:' ('true' = 'true' ) ' }}]}  
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1099)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:159)  
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:348)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1008)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:159)  
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:348)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromJSONTokener(JSONArray.java:1131)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:125)  
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:351)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1008)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1201)  
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:165)  
    at br.com.michel.json.JsonTest.main(JsonTest.java:28)
```

The output of the json that I desire:

{"ga": [{"c": {"f", "C #", "o": "=", "v1": "('true' = 'true')"}}]}

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the single quotes with backslashes (which themselves have to be escaped since we're working with a Java string literal):

```
String json = "{gA:[ {c:{f:'C#',o:'=',v1:' (\\'true\\' = \\'true\\' ) ' }}]}";
```

Running the code with the modified `json` variable produces this output:

```
{"gA":[{"c":{"f":"C#","o":"=","v1":" ('true' = 'true' ) "}}]}
```

This string differs from your desired output in that it has the element `v1` instead of `u` and the value isn't trimmed.  I'm not sure if that's a copy/paste typeo or not, though.  If that's what you're after, it's simple enough to modify your parsed `JSONObject`.

Comment: Thanks buddy.

Last night I had found this solution too, the mistake I was making was only put a backslash and not two.

About i had put the wrong exit, the desired output is the same.

{"ga": [{"c": {"f", "C #", "o": "=", "v1", "('true' = 'true')"}}]}

Thank you friend.

Answer (score 0):

Dude more when I'm putting this Json:

{gA:[{c:{f:'FIXO',o:'=',v1:'T'}},{gO:[{c:{f:'ID_USUARIO',o:'=',vc:'200'}},{c:{f:'ID_PERFIL',o:'=',vc:'28'}},{c:{f:'C#',o:'=',v1:'(\'true\' = \'true\')'}}]}]}

Overflows this exception:

net.sf.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 131 of {gA:[{c:{f:'FIXO',o:'=',v1:'T'}},{gO:[{c:{f:'ID_USUARIO',o:'=',vc:'1'}},{c:{f:'ID_PERFIL',o:'=',vc:'1'}},{c:{f:'C#',o:'=',v1:'(\'true\' = \'true\')'}}]}]}

Comment: huh?  What is this answer?